# Curvature of parallel curve for a regular plane curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves

Let $\gamma$ be a regular plane curve and let $\lambda$ be a constant. The **parallel** curve $\gamma^\lambda$ of $\gamma$ is defined as $$\gamma^\lambda(t)=\gamma(t)+\lambda n_s(t)$$ where $n_s$ is the **normal** of the tangent line.

**Question:**

> Let $\kappa_s(t)$ be the signed curvature of $\gamma$ at $t$.
>
> Show that if $\lambda\kappa_s(t)\neq1$  then $\gamma$ is a regular
>   curve and its signed curvature is
>   $\frac{\kappa_s}{|1-\lambda\kappa_s(t)|}$.

**My work so far:**

$\gamma^\lambda(t)=\gamma(t)+\lambda n_s(t)$ $\implies$ $\frac{d\gamma^\lambda(t)}{d s^\lambda}\frac{ds^\lambda}{dt} = \frac{d\gamma(t)}{ds}\frac{ds}{dt}+\lambda\frac{dn_s(t)}{ds}\frac{ds}{dt}$.

Let $T_\gamma(t)$ denote the tangent vector of $\gamma$ at $t$. Since $n_s'=-\kappa_sT$ we have:

$T_{\gamma^\lambda}\frac{ds^\lambda}{dt} = T_\gamma\frac{ds}{dt}+\lambda(-\kappa_sT_\gamma)\frac{ds}{dt}$ $\implies$ $T_{\gamma^\lambda}\frac{ds^\lambda}{dt} = (1-\lambda\kappa_s)T_\gamma\frac{ds}{dt}$.

I think that implies that $\frac{ds^\lambda}{dt} = |(1-\lambda\kappa_s)|\frac{ds}{dt}$, since $T_{\gamma^\lambda}$ and $T_\gamma$ are co-linear, and the variance of one is described in relation to the other.

I don't know where to go from here, but this feels like the right direction. Also, I'm not really sure what the geometric sense of what I'm proving is. So any advice is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For future readers, have a look at Gibson "Elementary geometry of differentiable curves", around page 122.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you read Do Carmo, and this is an excercise. Let me use $\beta (t)$ for $\gamma^\lambda$, 
$$\beta'(t)=(1-\lambda k(s)).\frac{ds}{dt}.\frac{d\gamma}{ds}\\
\beta'(t)=(1-\lambda k(s)).\frac{1}{k(s)}.\frac{d\gamma}{ds}\\
\frac{d\beta}{ds^\lambda} \frac{ds^\lambda}{dt}=(1-\lambda k(s)).\frac{1}{k(s)}.\frac{d\gamma}{ds}\\
\frac{d\beta}{ds^\lambda} \frac{1}{k_\lambda (s^\lambda)}=(1-\lambda k(s)).\frac{1}{k(s)}.\frac{d\gamma}{ds}\\$$
Note that $|\frac{d\beta}{ds^\lambda}|=1$ and $|\frac{d\gamma}{ds}|=1$ and finally that $1-\lambda k(s)\ne0$, then the result.

Comment: Wonderful! That makes great sense. Thanks for helping me out. I actually haven't read Do Carmo. This question is from "Elementary Differential Geometry" by Pressley, published by Springer.

Comment: Why is ds/dt = 1/k(s) - I cannot derive it from anywhere?