# Curvature of parallel curves

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

This question has an answer here: [Curvature of parallel curve for a regular plane curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658135/curvature-of-parallel-curve-for-a-regular-plane-curve) but I do not understand it for two reasons, 1) being that I don't see the justification for $\frac{ds}{dt} = 1/k$ and also 2) by taking absolute values at the end, he actually loses the sign needed for the result.

With that out of the way, the question is to prove that for a parallel curve $\alpha_\lambda(t) = \alpha(t) + \lambda n(t)$ that $k_\lambda = \frac{k}{|1-\lambda k|}$.

My attempt is:
\begin{align*}
\alpha_\lambda &= \alpha + \lambda n \\
\frac{d\alpha}{ds_\lambda}\frac{ds_\lambda}{dt} &= \frac{d\alpha}{ds}\frac{ds}{dt} + \lambda \frac{dn}{ds}\frac{ds}{dt} \\
\frac{d\alpha}{ds_\lambda}|\alpha_\lambda '| &= \mathbf{t}|\alpha '| - \lambda k\mathbf{t}|\alpha '| \\
\frac{d\alpha}{ds_\lambda}|\alpha_\lambda '| &= \mathbf{t}|\alpha '|(1 - \lambda k).
\end{align*}

Then by taking absolute value, we get
$$
|\alpha_\lambda '| = |\alpha '||1 - \lambda k|.
$$
This gets me the $|1 - \lambda k|$ term, but I have no idea how to get $k$ nor $k_\lambda$ from what I have left.

Comment: Is $\alpha$ arclength-parametrized to start with? What does the prime mean? I recommend you use the arclength parameter for $\alpha$.

Comment: No $\alpha$ is not arclength-paremetrized. The prime means differenatiation with respect to whatever variable $\alpha$ is defined with (in this case t).

Comment: So, use $\mathbf t_\lambda = \mathbf t$ (at least for small $\lambda$) and differentiate with respect to respective arclengths to get curvatures. You also have more information. Do not take magnitudes.

Comment: I can't differentiate directly with respect to the arclength parameters, since they are different on each side of the equation. That's why I'm differentiating w.r.t. $t$ and using the chain rule. I really don't want to differentiate again to get curvature, since then I would have to deal with $k$ being a function of $s$, and solve the diff. eq.

Comment: I didn’t tell you to differentiate your equation. I told you to differentiate the unit tangent vectors with respect to their respective arclengths.

Comment: I don't see how that helps.

Comment: Because that's how you compute curvature?

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, but I DO have to use the equation eventually to get the relation I need. Your "hints" aren't helping.